# Show $ \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{(1+\sec^2t)\sqrt{\sec t}}{ (1+\sec t)^2-2}dt= \frac\pi{\sqrt2}$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I try to figure out how to deal with the trigonometric integral

$$ \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{(1+\sec^2t)\sqrt{\sec t}}{ (1+\sec t)^2-2}dt
$$
which is supposed to be equal to $\frac\pi{\sqrt2}$. Despite the simplicity of the result, it does not seem easy. What is troublesome is the square-root part in the integrand, which renders known techniques, such as half-angle substitution, ineffective.

I also threw it into WA, which churns out a complicated antiderivative expression in elliptical functions not all that helpful.

Comment: Where did you encounter this integral? Is it a part of a bigger problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh - It was presented to me by a colleague who has been struggling with it for sometimes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{(1+\sec^2t)\sqrt{\sec t}}{(1+\sec t)^2-2}\,dt\stackrel{u=\frac{\sin t}{\sqrt{\cos t}}}=2\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{u^2+2}=\frac\pi{\sqrt2}$$

Comment: To see how I arrived at that substitution, rewrite the integral as $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1+\cos^2t}{\sqrt{\cos t}(1+2\cos t-\cos^2t)}\,dt=2\int_0^1\frac{\frac1{x^4}+1}{\left(\frac1{x^2}+2-x^2\right)\sqrt{\frac1{x^2}-x^2}}x\,dx$$ where $x=\sqrt{\cos t}$. Then let $u=\sqrt{1/x^2-x^2}$.

Comment: Nothing beats this +1

Answer (score 1):

$$ I = \int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{(1+\sec^2t)\sqrt{\sec t}}{ (1+\sec t)^2-2}dt $$

$1.$ Put $\sec t = x^2$

$$I = 2 \int_1^\infty \frac{(x^4 + 1)}{\sqrt{x^4-1}(x^4 + 2x^2 - 1)}dx$$

$2.$ Put $x^2 - \frac{1}{x^2} = y^2$

$$I = 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{dy}{y^2+2} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$